# JS: Why value of "x" variable is undefined?

Tags: javascript, function, hoisting

Why is the `x` variable in the example below returning `undefined` rather than 25?

```js
var x = 25;

(function() {
  console.log(x);
  var x = 10;
})();
```

Comment: Variable hoisting inside a closure.

Comment: [Does this help answer your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work?rq=1)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/30469825/7662112

Comment: you can do like this `var x = 25;

(function(x) {
  console.log(x);
})(x);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is common problem of [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) in javascript.The code actually looks like this.The value is assigned after the `console.log`.

The second undefined(if run on developer's tool) is because the function is not explicitly returning anything

This is how Javascript actually executes your code due to `var` hoisting:

```js
var x = 25;

(function() {
  var x;
  console.log(x);
  x = 10;
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's [Self-Invoking Functions](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_definition.asp) that will invoke without calling from specific function or place. and your declared `x` inside that function and preparing for running that function make `javascript` ignore global variable `x` and try to create local `x`.if you remove `var x = 10;` from the function inside then everything will be OK:

```js
var x = 25;

(function() {
  console.log(x);
})();
```