# Why greeter is undefined for first console.log?

Tags: javascript, function, scope

```
const greeter = 'CodeQuotient';

const sayHi = function greetings() 
{
 console.log(`${greeter} says, 'Hi!'`);
 
 var greeter = 'CQ';

 console.log(`${greeter} says, 'Hi!'`);
}﻿


sayHi();
```

If I run this code then output is

```
undefined says, 'Hi!'
CQ says, 'Hi!'
```

I want to ask why the first greeter for first console.log is **undefined**

and also if I remove the inner greeter variable then outer variable is assigned to both the console.logs
. Why?

```
const greeter = 'CodeQuotient';

const sayHi = function greetings() {
  console.log(`${greeter} says, 'Hi!'`);


  console.log(`${greeter} says, 'Hi!'`);
}﻿

sayHi();
```

And the output of above code after removing inner greeter variable is

```
CodeQuotient says, 'Hi!'

CodeQuotient says, 'Hi!'
```

Why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why a variable defined global is undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30469755/why-a-variable-defined-global-is-undefined)

Comment: Good old hoisting.