# I don't understand how vars behave

Tags: javascript, function, var

Can you guys please explain why this function logs "undefined world" ??? I'm confused...

```
var a = 'hello';
function b() {
  console.log(a);
  var a = 'world';
  console.log(a);
}
b();
```

Comment: The good thing about `var` is that you don't actually need to understand how it works because you should never use it. Use `let` and `const` instead.

Comment: Altought what @GuillaumeBrunerie mentioned is true, it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: The real reason of why it is happening is that `var` variables are hoisted, it means that the declaration is moved to the top of the enclosing function, so Javascript actually runs a `var a = undefined;` just at the beginning of the function.

Comment: As can be seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30469755/why-a-variable-defined-global-is-undefined

Comment: thank you guys so much! I'm trying to become a JS trainee and this var thing is in the test, so i have to learn it :c